# Logical OR query conditions in firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have two variables

```
user1 = eachData["user1"]
user2 = eachData["user2"]
```

i want to extract data from a collection of firestore when either of the following 2 condition is satisfied

```
condition 1: username = user1 and contactusername = user2
condition2: username = user2 and contactusername = user1
```

all the data which satisfies any one of the above two conditions has to be extracted.
i know to extract for one condition

```
refid = *****.where(u'timestamp', u'<=', end_time).where(u'timestamp', u'>=', start_time).order_by(u'timestamp', u'DESCENDING') #to extract data from timerange

query = refid.where(u'username', u'==', user1).where(u'contactusername', u'==', user2)
#extracts for condtion1
```

basically result should be

```
result = condition1 or condition2
```

how can i do it for multiple condition?

Comment: Firestore does not support logical OR queries across different fields.  You will have to perform two queries and merge the results in the client.

Comment: oh is it? cool thanks